# spacy's dependency matcher did not matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy, spacy-3

```
from spacy.tokenizer import DependencyMatcher
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
pattern = [
  
  {
    "RIGHT_ID": "number_like",
    "RIGHT_ATTRS": {"TEXT":{"REGEX":"\\d{10,18}"}}

  },

  {
    "LEFT_ID": "number_like",
    "RIGHT_ID": "NUMBERs",
    "RIGHT_ATTRS": {"TEXT":{"IN":['number','numbers','no']}},
    "REL_OP": "<",
  },

  {
   "LEFT_ID":"NUMBERs",
   "REL_OP":";",
   "RIGHT_ID":"keyword",
   "RIGHT_ATTRS": {"LEMMA":{"IN":['account','acc','accou']}}
    }



text_1 = ' account number 454546465 is extracted'
text_2 = 'account no 4545456654 is extracted' 
n1=doc(text_1)
n2 = doc(text_2)
matcher.DependencyMatcher(n1) ---> matches correctly
matcher.DependencyMatcher(n2) ---> word "no" not matches
```

pattern did not match word 'no'

the word "no" did not matches ,thing seems weird that i already put list of words but word-- 'no' not matches,
Need help

Comment: Checking the dependency parses in the web demo, they look quite different from each other, so it looks like your first rule is failing. For text like this the DependencyMatcher doesn't look like the right tool though, have you considered using the normal Matcher instead?

Comment: @polm23  a normal matcher finds out the static values, Hence I moved to a dependency matcher, my question is, why REL_OP in spacy vary from word to word? by referring link  https://spacy.io/api/dependencymatcher

Comment: @polm23 also using normal can't make relation of sentences, need help